# @EnvironmentObject not created correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to access an instance of the class

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var s: String = "test"
}
```

via the environment.
I instanciated it in Scene Delegate

```
  var m = MyModel()
```

Then I tried to put it into the environment with

```
let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
_ = contentView.environmentObject(m)
```

In contentview I reference it like

```
@EnvironmentObject var mod: MyModel
```

If I access it like

```
Text(mod.s)
```

the app crashes, saying "Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type MyModel found."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

> ```
> let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
> _ = contentView.environmentObject(m)
> ```

use

```
let contentView = ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(m)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

it is not a setter, it is view modifier that generates another view with injected environment object

Comment: Tnx!,  does the order matter?

Comment: Should not in this case, just a habit. You can try.

Comment: Order does not matter. It uses dynamic member lookup.